# Angular 2 validate that one date input is equal to or before another

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, bootstrap-datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I have two inputs which are populated by two Angular 2 Bootstrap `datepickers`. I want my button that corresponds to the `FormGroup` to be disabled if `startDate` is after (not before or equal to) `endDate`. Right now if I choose a `startDate` that is later than `endDate` the submit button stays enabled. But if I then click the second calendar button to get the second `datepicker` to pop up, the submit button becomes disabled (I don't actually have to choose the `endDate`). I checked with the console and `startDate`,`endDate`, and `error` are all changing and changing to the correct values at the correct times with no errors, it's just the disabling of the submit button that has off "timing".

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div>
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!secondForm.controls['startDate'].valid && secondForm.controls['startDate'].touched}">
  <label>Start Date:</label>
  <input style="width:250px" [value]="getDate('start')" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="secondForm.controls['startDate']">
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <ngb-datepicker id="special" *ngIf="startCheck;" [(ngModel)]="startDate" (ngModelChange)="showDatePick(0)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ngb-datepicker>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn icon-calendar" (click)="showDatePick(0)"></button>
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!secondForm.controls['endDate'].valid && secondForm.controls['endDate'].touched}">
  <label>End Date:</label>
  <input style="width:250px" [value]="getDate('end')" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="secondForm.controls['endDate']">
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <ngb-datepicker id="special" *ngIf="endCheck;" [(ngModel)]="endDate" (ngModelChange)="showDatePick(1)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ngb-datepicker>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn icon-calendar" (click)="showDatePick(1)"></button>
<button type="submit" class="btn icon-search" [disabled]="!secondForm.valid || error==true"></button>
</div>
</form>
```

Corresponding Typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbDateStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {DatePipe} from "@angular/common";
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
selector: 'calendar-pick',
styleUrls: ['../app.component.css'],
templateUrl: './calendarpick.component.html',
providers: [DatePipe]
})

export class CalendarPickComponent {
public error: boolean = false;
public dt: NgbDateStruct;
public dt2: NgbDateStruct;
public startCheck: boolean = false;
public endCheck: boolean = false;
secondForm : FormGroup;

public constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private datePipe: DatePipe) {
this.secondForm = fb.group({
  'startDate' : [this.dt, Validators.required],
  'endDate' : [this.dt2, Validators.required]
})
this.secondForm.valueChanges.subscribe( (form: any) => {
    console.log('form changed to:', form);
  }
);
}

public getDate(dateName: string) {
let workingDateName = dateName + 'Date';
let timestamp = this[workingDateName] != null ? new Date(this[workingDateName].year, this[workingDateName].month-1, this[workingDateName].day).getTime() : new Date().getTime();
this.secondForm.controls[dateName + 'Date'].setValue(this.datePipe.transform(timestamp, 'longDate'));
}

public showDatePick(selector):void {
if(selector === 0) {
  this.startCheck = !this.startCheck
} else {
  this.endCheck = !this.endCheck;
}
this.periodValidator(this.secondForm);
}

periodValidator(formGroup:FormGroup) {
let s = new Date(formGroup.value.startDate);
let e = new Date(formGroup.value.endDate);
let stDt = moment(s);
let endDt = moment(e);
if (stDt > endDt) {
  this.error = true;
}else {
  this.error = false;
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a custom validator and assign it to the form group as a whole like so:

```
endDateAfterOrEqualValidator(formGroup): any {
    var startDateTimestamp, endDateTimestamp;
    for(var controlName in formGroup.controls) {
      if(controlName.indexOf("startDate") !== -1) {
        startDateTimestamp = Date.parse(formGroup.controls[controlName].value);
      }
      if(controlName.indexOf("endDate") !== -1) {
        endDateTimestamp = Date.parse(formGroup.controls[controlName].value);
      }
    }
    return (endDateTimestamp < startDateTimestamp) ? { endDateLessThanStartDate: true } : null;
  }
```

This will check the timestamps of the control and return *something if it is not valid* and null if it is valid.

```
this.secondForm = fb.group({
    'startDate' : ['', Validators.required],
    'endDate'  : ['', Validators.required]
  },
  {validator: this.endDateAfterOrEqualValidator});
```

I suppose if you don't intend to add any additional controls you could hardcode the assignments of the timestamps instead of checking the controls for the values you want.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yow6DMd2soBXwJ2oGOFu?p=preview

Comment: I also want to add a small alert message if this validation error occurs. It's just a `div` tag but having trouble getting it to pop up using `*ngIf`. I tried setting `this.error=true;` in the `endDateAfterOrEqualValidator` function and then have `*ngIf="error"` in the `div` tag. Also tried `*ngIf="secondForm.hasError('endDateLessThanStartDate')"` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Was able to use the second solution after putting `enableProdMode()` in my `main.ts` file after my import statements

Comment: Is there a less "hacky" way of doing this?

Comment: `<div [hidden]="!secondForm.hasError('endDateLessThanStartDate')">show me</div>` works without error (and without `enableProMode()`), less hacky but still leaves me wondering if there's a better way to set everything up.

Answer (score 0):

For my date-picker component I have used this code as a validator.

```
if(this.dateFrom && this.dateTo) {

    var d1 = Date.parse(this.dateTo);
    var d2 = Date.parse(this.dateFrom);

       if (d1 > d2) {
           this.error = true;
       }
}
```

This should work for yours if it is in a standard javascript or moment date format. Also in the **if** statement provided you could set a variable of error = true and this would then trigger a error message as follows.

```
<button [disabled]="error"></button>
```

Hope this plunker helps: [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uRCN1l8IPmodzIk8To5H)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but doesn't really help since I'm working with typescript and I need the validation to coordinate with the disabling and enabling of my button @DavidR2016

Comment: I'm working in typescript a well. and [disabled]="error" with the above code should sort it.

Comment: Sorry, but just a little confused on actually where in my typescript I throw that code, as well as the `div` tag and `[disabled]="error"`

Comment: Also not sure about my date format since it prints for example `Friday, November 4, 2016`

Comment: Sorry, Basically the periodValidator function is the same. if that logic works, instead of returning null, set this.error = true. and then where you have your button that already has the [disabled] attribute just add '&& error ' next to the existing code in there.

Comment: heres an example for you to try https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview

Comment: I edited my original code. Note `[disabled]="!secondForm.valid && error"` in my button, the addition of `public error: boolean;` at the top of the class,  the addition of `, {}, this.periodValidator` at the end of the FormBuilder constructor, and the complete change to the `periodValidator` function. I'm sure it's something to do with the way I'm calling/using that function.

Comment: I edited my code again which has my `showDatePick` function calling `periodValidator` which has the correct logic (I checked by printing `this.error` to console). I still have `[disabled]` in my button checking for `error` to be true but it's still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: So the console.log shows that it sets to true? the only thing i can see is that you have [disabled]="!secondForm.valid || error==true" when it should be [disabled]="!secondForm.valid || error"

Comment: It actually looks like it works, but the only thing is that after choosing the first date I have to click on the other `datepicker` in order to get it to notice.

Comment: It seems that periodValidator will only set error to true if it has both start and end values which would mean you would have to interact with both date-pickers.

Comment: Well it's setting `error` to true by only picking the first date. I don't even have to pick the second date, I just have to open the `datepicker` in order for the button to get disabled.

Comment: Try wrapping your if statement that sets the error status in another if statement to check the values exist before executing the code. e.g if(stDt && endDt) {your existing if statement}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127553/discussion-between-drew13-and-davidr2016).